# Index on array field not being effective

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I have the following collection, with around 600 entries, that represents cooking recipes:

```
"name":"",
"ingredients":[]
"steps":""
"dificulty:""
}
```

The items inside the ingredients array have the following structure

```
"id":"",
"name":""
}
```

Some recipes are more demanding and can have an array of 20+ ingredients.

When doing a `.find("ingredients.id":"12345")` to get the results takes me almost 7/8 seconds.
Meanwhile created an index for the field but the loading time keeps the same.

```
{
    "ingredients.id" : 1
}
```

Checked the "explain" tab on the mongo dbcompass and it confirms that the created index is being used.

the IXSCAN shows:

```
{
 "stage": "IXSCAN",
 "nReturned": 28,
 "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
 "works": 29,
 "advanced": 28,
 "needTime": 0,
 "needYield": 0,
 "saveState": 0,
 "restoreState": 0,
 "isEOF": 1,
 "keyPattern": {
  "ingredients.id": 1
 },
 "indexName": "recipes_ingredients _id",
 "isMultiKey": true,
 "multiKeyPaths": {
  "ingredients.id": [
   "ingredients "
  ]
 },
 "isUnique": false,
 "isSparse": false,
 "isPartial": false,
 "indexVersion": 2,
 "direction": "forward",
 "indexBounds": {
  "ingredients .id": [
   "[\"12345\", \"12345\"]"
  ]
 },
 "keysExamined": 28,
 "seeks": 1,
 "dupsTested": 28,
 "dupsDropped": 0,
 "parentName": "FETCH"
}
```

This seems a really straightforward situation but it is showing to be highly inefficient, any ideas how to improve?

Comment: In general, 600 document collection (even with array field) query should be faster than the mentioned 7 or 8 seconds. The query plan you had posted is not showing the 6 or 8 seconds...?

Comment: Yes, it does not show. It looks like all is well, but it isn't

Comment: If you are connecting to the database over the network (issues), or having insufficient memory and other issues can be the cause. May be there are too many programs running in the memory. You can also see how much space (in MB) the index occupies in the Compass. You can try running the explain using the "allPlansExecution" mode. Also, include information about the server platform, version and related details in the post.